# A video player that fully loads streaming files?

Tags: video, media-player, streaming

I have a terrible encoded video. It crashes ffmpeg and is nearly unusable. VLC can play it, it cant transcode it. I manage to find a plugin for virtualdub but theres still an issue with sound. The problem is bad timestamps. It goes ahead 20mins (near the begining), backwards 10seconds at random times etc etc. VirtualDub cant get the sound sync

Is there a media player like vlc that can play FLV files (FLV1, NELL) but loads all/most of the file so i can jump around AND have sync'd audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caching in [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html) is adjustable and it can also play flash video (*.flv) if you have the needed library installed (e.g. libgstflva for linux). It is available for a number of platforms.

To set the cache size to 5,000 kBytes you would start it with (assuming you run from the shell)

```
mplayer -cache 5000 VIDEO.flv
```

There are other caching options listed in the manual. Most of them can also be set via the GUI.

Comment: The video is pretty evil. mplayer (GUI, i used `MPlayer SVN Windows with SMPlayer GUI (recommended)` on the download page) kind of played it but not really. and i couldnt seek because it would lock up or stall so i dont think having cache matter (which i found a place to specify cmd line args)

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening the file in a program like [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/), then save in another format, e.g. MP4.  Avidemux will index it correctly.

Comment: That video is deadly, it caused the app to crash. On playback and encoding